# invalid use of non-static datamember Ui_Mainwindow::(Pushbutton) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have defined some `QTableWidget` by using inheritance and some buttons by Qt Creator.

Now I'm trying to connect a signal from my button to a slot from my `QTableWidget`.

Here in `main()` I have defined my Food object of self defined(re-defined) `QTableWidget`:

```
Table Food(&w,3,700,50,610,getdata_foodtabel());
```

And in next line I tried to connect it with my `QPushButton` object(orderButton):

```
QObject::connect(Ui::MainWindow::orderButton, SIGNAL(w.on_orderButton_clicked()),&Food, SLOT(Food.get_number()));
```

And in this line I get this error:

```
 error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Ui_MainWindow::orderButton'
 QPushButton *orderButton;
              ^
```

And also get number is a self defined public slot in Table class

can any body tell me why is this error for?
and what should I do to fix it?

my  table's constructor int Table.cpp:

```
Table::Table(QWidget *Parent,int row,int X,int Y,int height,std::vector     <std::vector <std::string > > food)
  :QTableWidget(food.size(),3,Parent)
{

this->setGeometry(QRect(X,Y,321,height));
this->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-color: rgb(206, 255, 255);"));
this->row=food.size();
for(int i=0;i<this->row;i++)
        this->food.push_back(food[i]);
for (int i=0;i<this->row;i++)
{
  //  this->food[i][0]=names[i];
   // this->food[i][1]=costs[i];
    this->setCellWidget(i,0,new label(QString::fromStdString(food[i][0])));
    this->setCellWidget(i,1,new label (QString::fromStdString(food[i][1])));
    this->setCellWidget(i,2,new QSpinBox);
}

 }
```

and my main function:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Table Drinks(&w,3,40,50,280,getdata_drinktabel());
       Drinks.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("نوشیدنی;قیمت;تعداد").split(";"));
       Table Desert(&w,3,40,380,280,getdata_desertabel());
        Desert.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("دسر;قیمت;تعداد").split(";"));
        Table Appetizer(&w,3,370,50,610,getdata_beforetabel());
        Appetizer.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("پیش غذا;قیمت;تعداد").split(";"));
        Table* Food=new Table(&w,3,700,50,610,getdata_foodtabel());
        Food->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString(" غذا;قیمت;تعداد").split(";"));
        Food->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-image: url(:/soltani-edited1.jpg);"));
        QObject::connect(Ui::MainWindow::orderButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),Food, SLOT(Food.get_number()));
        w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more code, but I'd guess you have a class `MainWindow` that has a member `orderButton`.  It seems like you are trying to use `MainWindow::orderButton` as an argument to connect, instead of a *specific* `Mainwindow`s `orderButton`

Comment: Correct Syntax would be `QObject::connect(orderButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),&Food, SLOT(get_number()));` or `connect(orderButton, &QPushButton::clicked, &Food, &Table::get_number);` How you declare and use Food here suggests that it's created on the stack and won't survive the method where it's created. Try creating it on the heap instead.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld

The error is about orderButton...
and also I defined Food dynamically( you meaned it...right??) and it didn't work

Comment: actually I tried to address a   'QTablewidget'  like this:
' Ui::MainWindow::tableWidget ' and I still get this error : 'error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Ui_MainWindow::tablewidget''

Comment: dwcanillas already told you what the error is, you have to connect a _specific_ button, something like `QObject::connect(&w.pushbuttonname, SIGNAL(...` and then use the name of your pushButton

Comment: `Ui_MainWindow::orderButton` is not a static member, you cannot access it like that. Either add a method in your `MainWindow` class that returns a pointer to `orderButton`, or connect the button's signal to a signal in `MainWindow` and then connect that signal to your `Food::get_number` slot (as shown by Frank, your syntax is wrong there too).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in another way...

I just inherited a class from `QPushButton` and connected it's signal to `Food`'s slot.